libertine.sty' not found
The latest update of the libertine package (5.3.0) does not work with MikTeX anymore. It just gives a 'libertine.sty' not found' error. I'm running texstudio 4.8.4 with MikTeX 24.1 on window 10. Any Ideas?
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{article}
    
\usepackage{libertine}
    
\begin{document} 
test  
\end{document}


That is not due to the updated package. The error shows the package is not installed (correctly) so the version is irrelevant.

Probably true. I used the MikTeX update mechanism, which should install the updated package. But there is not .sty file in the usual MikTex folder.

Indeed it seems, that the file list of the current version of MiKTeX package libertine does not show libertine.sty. There is already an issue in the tracker. So this bug has been reported. (Otherwise I would have asked you to do it. ;-) )

I’m voting to close this question because this question refers to a bug which has been fixed and the answer won't help anybody ever.

Got the same problem here...

ok, it works again if I manually download the libertine package, copy it into the miktex/tex/latex folder and manually refresh the filename database in MikTeX. This is probably not the intended way to do this, though.

By mistake an incomplete archive was uploaded to CTAN.  This was corrected the next day.  Presumably, MiKTeX installed the incomplete package before it was updated.

As far as I can tell, anyone who, today, installs the latest Basic MiKTeX with the latest updates, will meet the error: "libertine.sty not found". That being the case, why has this question been closed, and what can be done to correct the matter?

Complain to the MiKTeX developer but the issue has been reported to their bug tracker.  In the meantime, simply unzip the libertine.tds.zip from CTAN and update your file-name database.

I've unzipped the CTAN correct version and opened the MiKTeX console. The offending file appears to be LinLiibertineTZI-osf-ts1.tfm.  This file name does not appear in the extracted file list.  Is this file perhaps misnamed?  Should it, in fact, be LinLibertineTZI-tosf-s1.tfm? - the "t" is misplaced.

@keith77777 Did you update the font-name database?

Yes, I did all three of the update commands.

I have now replaced - globally - every \libertineSB command with \mdseries so as to move forward.  Will watch out for an update from MiKTeX.

The tfm and vf file names are automatically generated by otftotfm so a typo is unlikely. There may be a typo in libertine.sty.  If you think there's an issue, send a report to the package maintainer including a MWE that shows the issue.

Thanks, I will await the expected update from the maintainer.
